# C# Outlook mailItem.HTMLBody is Empty

Tags: c#, html, outlook, add-in

I'm working on an Outlook Add in, and I want to look for some specific tags in the html of the mail that the user is reading. For that matter, I'm using the ActiveExplorer's Selection change event.

```
currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook
                .ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler
                (CurrentExplorer_Event);


 private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
        {
                if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count == 1)
                {
                    Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                    if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {

                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                        lookForTags(mailItem.HTMLBody);
                     }
                 } 
         }
```

The problem is that for it to work the user has to click on the mail item twice because the first time, mail is still loading and and `mailItem.HTMLBody` returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 08.01.0240.003">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then the second time, mail is done loading so mailItem.HTMLBody returns the real body and everything works fine. Is there any other event that is fired when the mail is done loading so that I can start executing my code? Or is there a better solution to avoid having an empty HTMLBody?

Comment: What kind of message store is this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the cached Exchange mode?

Typically the item is already available in the [SelectionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813(v=office.15).aspx) event handler. There is no need to wait. What Outlook version do you have installed on the PC?

Also I'd suggest releasing underlying COM objects instantly. Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2010.

Comment: Did you try to review the code and add the release statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open event

```
Inspectors allInspectors;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            allInspectors = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors;
            allInspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);

        }


        void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                mailItem.Open += new ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(MailItemOpen);

            }
        }

        public void MailItemOpen(ref bool Cancel)
        {
            var mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            string text = mailItem.HTMLBody;
        }
```